# Problem passing data from the controller to the view Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm getting an error when I try to pass data from the controller to the view and I spent a lot of time trying to solve it. The error is "Undefined Variable $instEntNacs". There is other form this view, because depending on the rol, it will show the first or the second one.

Here's the controller "ConvenioController":

```php
public function create()
    {
        $instEntNacs = DB::table('inst_ent_nacs')->select('id', 'nombre')->get();
        return view('convenios.create', ['instEntNacs' => $instEntNacs]);
    }
```

And the view:

```html
@if (auth()->user()->rol_id == "2")
    <form method="POST" class="form-conv-nac border border-2 rounded-3 shadow-lg" action="{{ route('convenios.store_nac') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-1 col-10 mt-4">
                <select class="form-control border border-dark" id="con_instEntNac" name="con_instEntNac">
                    <option selected value="">-- Institución o Entidad --</option>
                    @foreach ($instEntNacs as $item)
                        <option value="{{ $item->id }}"> {{ $item->nombre }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4 mb-5">
                <div class="offset-1 col-2">
                    <a  href="{{ route('login.activites') }}">Regresar</a>
                </div>
            <div class="offset-2 col-3">
                <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn_2 btn-danger rounded-pill border border-dark">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn_1 btn-primary rounded-pill border border-dark">Registrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </form>
@endif
```

Comment: Have you tried with `return view('convenios.create', compact('instEntNacs'));`?

Comment: @harunB10 Compacting a variable makes no difference. It will still return the same `array`.

If this is the full view, you shouldn't be getting any exceptions. Are you certain there is no PHP script inside your view that might be unsetting the variable (`unset($instEntNacs)`)? Are you also certain the create view is the one you're working in?

Comment: Are you Changing the correct file? Please confirm this, just comment these line `@foreach ($instEntNacs as $item)<option value="{{ $item->id }}"> {{ $item->nombre }}</option>@endforeach` and see if it throwing error or not. Even after  commenting this, it is throwing errror. it might be because you are edititng some cache file. `php artisan view:clear` might help on this one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$data['instEntNacs'] = DB::table('inst_ent_nacs')->select('id', 'nombre')->get();
return view('convenios.create')->with($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `compact('instEntNacs')` with `return view('convenios.create')`.

`return view('convenios.create', compact('istEntNacs'));`